# mschart: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization - vs2015 - winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015, mschart

I have a windows form application (framework 3.5) that uses msCharts.
Since we have upgraded our project from VS2008 to VS2015 we get the following error on other computers where we deploy the program (and where mschart is not installed):

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization', Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified. 
File name: 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

We are using 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects' to create the installer (.msi) for the program.

In the Setup project I'm also not seeing any 'mschart/datavisualization' items in the 'Detected Dependencies' list, so maybe this is the problem? But I don't know if that is required.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of the framework do you have the project set to?  I think if it's set to an older version you need to include the dll, otherwise it comes packaged in .NET 4 and greater.

Comment: We use framework 3.5. I don't know how to include the dll to the dependencies of the setup project

Comment: You should just add the dll to your main project, then when you make a standard deploy it includes all the dll automatically.  There should be a dependency folder where it puts them all.  If it's not in there, you can add the dll manually yourself.  You'll have to get the dll from Microsoft if you dont have them.

Comment: The dll is included in the main project, but not in the dependency folder from the setup project. And the problem is I don't know how to add it to the dependency folder.

Comment: It might be easiest to just delete the deploy project and make a new one.  It should then add all the dll from your project.  If that isn't an option, under the deploy project you have to go into the File System Editor and delete the output file type and re-add it.  The dependencies should refresh.

Comment: Finally got it to work, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to manually add the .DLL's to the assemblies in my setup project.